# Windows 7 professional 64bit access XPE shared folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares

There are many sites about this problem but no one of them works for me.

I have Windows 7 proffesional 64bit and two XPE (windows XP embedded) machines.

And probably this "embedded" is not important because i remember same frustrations connecting simple XP too.

However:

- Both XPE machines can see win7pro64 shared folder
- win7pro for one machine asking for password, on other saying "Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."
- I have windows7home in the same network and it sees both XPE shared folders (with registry values shown below).

What i have tried:

1. setting HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel to valuese 0,1 and 2.
2. setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\UseMachineId to 1

all other sites talk always about this same thing through secpol.msc, so i would prefere regedit answer if possible. without "click this click that windows supidity" that i have read so many times.

also it would be grate to have solution by changing win7pro64 options (because win7home already see it, and because XPE machines are property of some industrial providers that i can not play much with).

Comment: Are these computers in a domain? Are you using the same user account with the same password on all three computers?

Comment: @Twisty no domain involved. users different. if all users needs to be the same to access everyone-allowed shares, then microsoft should delete term `user`.

Answer (score 0):

[this post](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/78350-45-solved-error-1385-logon-failure-user) on tomshardware has good informations.

so to sumarize my experience, this is what i have found regarding my problems:

- lm/ntlm/ compatibility and usemachineid are uninportant. it was maybe importantant for win98/95, but not for xp. I have installed for this test XP-pro without any service pack, and it has all the same options for this, nothing new 15 years after.
- xpe 'embeded' is unimportant too, same problems for home/pro editions.
- to access some share it must be either GUEST-way or USER-way
- for GUEST-way, destination comupter needs to have 1) guest user enabled 2) guest user removed from "deny access to this computer from network" in secpol.msc 3) security model "guest" in secpol.msc
- for USER-way, destination computer needs to 1) turn off guest user and 2) set security model to "classic" in secpol.msc ... and 3) source computer (from which accessing destination) needs to send one of destination's user/password credentials.
- destination share put to 'everyone enabled everything'
- do not waste time on msdn forums, avoid their missleading answers.
- some systems will work with fewer setting (like win7home misteriosly in this question), some not right away, but there are just 5-6 options to play inside security policy, and they are well named and explained.
- use regedit alternatives for home/embeded systems that lacks userinterface options.
- use just IP addresses until manage access. domains, workgroups and homegroups are evil that started this win-networking mess.
- turn off firewall, antivirus and set UAC to zero.